# How to check pressed key modifier on view action?

Tags: ember.js

I've got the following handlebar template code in Ember.js

```
<div {{action "testAction" target="App.testController" allowedKeys="alt"}}>TEST</div>
```

How could I check, in the "testAction" handler, if the "alt" key was pressed or not and behave according to that ?

For example, if testAction increment a variable, I want it incremented by a step of 10 instead of 1 if the "alt" key was pressed.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do this with actions; they either send the click event or not. See [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-whitelisted-modifier-keys) for details.

You can achieve what you want by putting a specific event handler in the view:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({

  mouseDown: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
})
```